# Get value from Swift dictionary of type [AnyHashable:URL]

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm calling a web service and it returns the data which is a dictionary of type `[AnyHashable:URL]`. For the key, I know exactly its type, which is String. So I've tried to get the URL by using:

```
streamURLs[AnyHashable("36")]
streamURLs["36"]
streamURLs[36]
```

However, it always returns `nil`.
Therefore, I've had to use `for` loop as follows:

```
for (key,val) in (streamURLs)! {
    let val_str = "\(key)"
    if val_str == "36" {
        remoteVideoURL = val
        break
    }
}
```

In fact, I want to access the URL directly by key, but I don't know how to do it. Can you suggest a solution

Comment: What is the value of `streamURLs!.keys.first`?

Comment: It is an Optional, for example: Optional(AnyHashable(247))

Comment: If you really have the right Dictionary of `[AnyHashable:URL]`, and its key actually is String, and the value for `"36"` exists, then `streamURLs["36"]` is the right way to get the value. Can you show us the output of `print(streamURLs)`?

Comment: Is that what the console outputted?

Comment: @Callam Yes, it's from the console

Comment: and what's the value when printing out streamURLs as @OOPer asked?

Comment: @OOPer: it is of the format: `Optional([AnyHashable(247): https://example.com,AnyHashable(24): https://example.com])`

Comment: Check your dictionaries keys `streamURLs.keys`

Comment: If the key of the Dictionary actually is String, you get something like this: `[AnyHashable("36"): http://example.com]`, double quotes are included in the output.

Comment: Check this: `print(type(of: streamURLs!.keys.first!.base))`.

Comment: @OOPer: It's Optional, e.g. `Optional(17)`

Comment: The `print` statement shown above should output typename. It's not the same as Callam's. And Optional cannot be contained in `AnyHashable`. Please try again exactly the same code as in my last comment.

Comment: @OOPer it doesn't compile if I keep your code. I've had to remove ! after `streamURLs` and it prints `Optional<Any>`

Comment: What is the exact code you have tried? Show all, it's not long.

Comment: @OOPer: Here it is: `print(type(of: streamURLs.keys.first!.base))`

Comment: OK, then, this part of your second code in your question `(streamURLs)!` should cause the same error, right?

Answer (score 0):

I think if u are sure that ur dictionary is not nil or empty try this:
This will unwrap ur optional, to be nil safe please check it with guard or if statment just to check nil safety.

> print((streamURLs!["36"])!)